# Using a value as an argument into another value in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, modelattribute

So lets say I have a `@ModelAttribute` of `userCredentials` which is a `List<String>` object.

and I have another `ModelAttribute` of type `Map<String,String>` of `roles`.

I can access them separately in *HTML* using *Thymeleaf* with:

```
${userCredentials.contains('<Hardcoded-value>')}
```

The problem i want the hardcoded value replaced and to use for example:

```
${userCredentials.contains('roles.client')}
```

Do you know how can i successfully use a model attribute as a parameter to the other model attribute. It works with the hardcoded values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Thymeleaf pre-processing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing):

```
${userCredentials.contains(__${roles.get('client')}__)}
```

Thymeleaf executes the preprocessing part in a first pass. So it will replace what is there with:

```
${userCredentials.contains(<result of roles.get() call here>)}
```

And then execute the template rendering.